# What's the best procedure to model a real world transformer which is not so simple

Tags: transformer, parasitic-capacitance

I have a transformer with a 110-1 turns ratio.

The output winding (1100 turns) is typically open circuit, with only its parasitic capacitances as a load.

The output winding has adjacent turn capacitance, layer to layer capacitance as well as capacitance of the output wires.

The input winding is 10 turns.

If I know the inductance and the ringing frequency on the output when pulsed, can I then determine the proper capacitance to put on an ideal transformer in modeling (LTSpice or similar)?

Assume air core so saturation isn't a problem.

Comment: It's kinda of a PITA with LTSpice to be honest. I've never been able to get a satisfactory model that takes saturation into account working.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading something about this in [The Art of Electronics: The x-Chapters](https://x.artofelectronics.net/) but it might have been just the saturation in a single inductor, not mutually coupled in a transformer.

Comment: Would [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/260547/95619) be of help? Also, you'll probably have to include an equivalent parallel resistance for some losses, too. Also interwindings capacitance, skin efect would be nice (if needed). In the end, you shouldn't expect a model to accurately reflect reality, but that doesn't mean you can't try.

Comment: I had a look thru X-Chapters but didn't see anything.

Comment: Yes you can transform the primary capacitance to secondary and select a secondary capacitance to match resonance of your 1:110 XFMR

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not formally accepting any answers to your 11 questions?